# How to set multiple value fetch from MySQL array and check array key

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to get value multiple value fetch from MySQL array and check array key exists or not.

I have two different table `booking_info` and `ticket_details` If both id is same the get the value from `ticket_details`

```
function getSeatInfo()
{
    global $getseatinfo;
    $id = 1;
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM booking_info WHERE id = '". $id . "'"; 
    $sqlr = "SELECT * FROM ticket_details WHERE id = '". $$sql . "'"; 
    $res = mysql_query($sqlr);

    $c=0;
    while ($a_row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        $getseatinfo[$c]["id"] = $a_row["id"];
        $getseatinfo[$c]["seat_number"] = $a_row["seat_number"];

        $c++;
    }
    return $getseatinfo;
}
```

**and check the value if exists or not**

```
global $getseatinfo;
$values=array('A1','A2','A3','B1','B2','B3');

if (array_key_exists($values,$getseatinfo)) {
    echo "Key exists!";
} else {
    echo "Key does not exist!";
}
```

Comment: loop and check it like this foreach($getseatinfo as $key=>$row) {  if(array_key_exists($key,$values)) { echo 'exists'; }  }

Comment: dont use single quotes for id beacause its not varchar

Answer (score 0):

do it one query like:

```
        $id = 1;
        $sql = "SELECT bi.id,td.* FROM booking_info bi WHERE bi id = '". $id."' "; 
        $sql .= "LEFT JOIN ticket_details td ON td.id = bi.id";
```

Comment: dont use single quotes for id beacause its not varchar

Comment: @jothi - its not sure, because the OP dont show the schema from the table ans **$id = 1;** looks like a sample

Comment: @BerndBuffen id is INT(10)

Comment: It show `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in` this error

Comment: do you use $res = mysql_query($qlr); ?? not $res = mysql_query($sqlr);